# How to set location header in Plumber API

Tags: r, http-headers, location, plumber

I would like to set location header in Plumber API response. So far I know how to assign status

```
res$status <- 202
```

and known how to access headers

```
res$headers
```

but how do I set `location header` is not clear.

Comment: Try `res$setHeader("Location", "./whatever-url-you-want.html")`

Comment: @MrFlick thank you, it worked. Also the following worked `res$headers$location <-"www.cnn.com" `